# Memory Allocation Issues Passing/Returning a Struct *Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

Please help me with my homework. I've got this program working just fine in debug mode, but as soon I use release mode it crashes with an abort().

I know it probably has something to do with memory allocation, but I don't understand pointers well enough.

Requirement is that I have to use an *array to dynamically allocate memory.

> "Your program should work for any number of students. When the program
>   starts, it should ask the user for the number of students to be
>   processed. Then it should dynamically allocate an array of that size
>   (array of student/score structures)."

I then need to, "Call a function to input the student name/score pairs and store them in the array."

So should I create the array in main or inside of the function? How can I return/pass the *array without messing up memory allocation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    string name;    //student's name
    int score;      //student's score
};

//function prototypes
void inputNameScore(Student*, int&);
void sortArray(Student* , int);
double avgScore(Student* , int);
void displayTable(Student* , int, double);

int main()
{   
    Student* arrayOfStudentPtr;     //pointer of type student to receive returned array pointer
    int numberOfStudents;           //number of students to be entered by user
    double average;                 //total score average   

    cout << "Please enter the number of students: ";
    cin >> numberOfStudents;

    arrayOfStudentPtr = new Student[numberOfStudents];  //dynamic array of type Student assigned to pointer

    inputNameScore(arrayOfStudentPtr, numberOfStudents);
    sortArray(arrayOfStudentPtr, numberOfStudents);
    average = avgScore(arrayOfStudentPtr, numberOfStudents);

    displayTable(arrayOfStudentPtr, numberOfStudents, average);    

    return 0;
}

void inputNameScore(Student* arrayOfStudentPtr, int& numberOfStudents)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Enter the name for student " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, arrayOfStudentPtr[i].name);
        cout << endl << "Enter the student's score: ";      
        cin >> arrayOfStudentPtr[i].score;
        while (arrayOfStudentPtr[i].score > 105 || arrayOfStudentPtr[i].score < 0)
        {
            cout << "Student's score can't be negative or greater than 105." << endl;
            cout << endl << "Enter the student's score: ";
            cin >> arrayOfStudentPtr[i].score;
        }
    }
}

void sortArray(Student* arrayOfStudentPtr, int numberOfStudents)
{
    Student Temp;   //holds a student struct object
    bool swap;      //swap is initialized to false at the start of each loop. If it is still false at end of loop we know there is nothing else to sort
    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++)
        {
            if (arrayOfStudentPtr[i].score > arrayOfStudentPtr[i + 1].score)
            {
                Temp = arrayOfStudentPtr[i];
                arrayOfStudentPtr[i] = arrayOfStudentPtr[i + 1];
                arrayOfStudentPtr[i + 1] = Temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}

double avgScore(Student* arrayOfStudentPtr, int numberOfStudents)
{
    int total;      //total of all grades
    double average; //average of all grades
    total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++)
    {
        total = arrayOfStudentPtr[i].score;
    }
    average = total / numberOfStudents;
    //average = static_cast<double>(total) / numberOfStudents;
    return average;
}

void displayTable(Student* arrayOfStudentPtr, int numberOfStudents, double average)
{   
    cout << endl << setw(31) << left << "Name" << setw(6) << right << "Score" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(31) << left << arrayOfStudentPtr[i].name << setw(6) << right << arrayOfStudentPtr[i].score << endl;
    }
    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << setw(31) << left << "Average: " << setw(6) << right << endl;
}
```

Comment: `arrayOfStudentPtr[i + 1]` in `sortArray` will access element outside array bounds,

Comment: Great, thank you so much for the answer! I can take it from here.

Comment: This is very bad style. Pointers and `new` should be avoided.  Are you forced to code this way by your class?

Comment: Only for this assignment. The book Starting Out With C++ Early Objects has a whole section in the pointers chapter about using dynamic memory allocation for an array so that we can let the user specify how large of an array to create. It was explained that it is one way to allow the user to enter as many things as they want. It did not delve into any other options nor did my instructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will work.

```
void sortArray(Student* arrayOfStudentPtr, int numberOfStudents)
    {
        Student Temp;   //holds a student struct object
        bool swap;      //swap is initialized to false at the start of each loop. If it is still false at end of loop we know there is nothing else to sort
        do
        {
            swap = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents-1; i++)
            {
                if (arrayOfStudentPtr[i].score > arrayOfStudentPtr[i + 1].score)
                {
                    Temp = arrayOfStudentPtr[i];
                    arrayOfStudentPtr[i] = arrayOfStudentPtr[i + 1];
                    arrayOfStudentPtr[i + 1] = Temp;
                    swap = true;
                }
            }
        } while (swap);
    }
```

Comment: Thank, I had just finished compiling just this when I came back here to say that Marcinj's suggestion helped me figure this out. I can't believe it all this time re-reading the chapter, and thinking I had pointers all wrong :-( Lesson learned I guess!